# Logstash and ElasticSearch filter Date @timestamp issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Im trying to index some data from file to `ElasticSearch` by using `Logstash`.

If I'm **not** using the `Date filter` in order to replace the `@timestamp`  everything works very well, but when in using the filter I do not get all the data.

I can't figure out why there is a difference  between the `Logstash command line` and `Elasticsearch` in the `@timestamp` value.

*Logstash conf*

```
filter { 
    mutate {
        replace => {
            "type" => "dashboard_a"
        }
    }
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP:Logdate} \[%{WORD:Severity}\] %{JAVACLASS:Class} %{GREEDYDATA:Stack}" ]
    }
    date {                        
        match => [ "Logdate", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }   
}
```

*Logstash Command line trace*

```
{
**"@timestamp" => "2014-08-26T08:16:18.021Z",**
   "message" => "26-08-2014 11:16:18,021 [DEBUG] com.fnx.snapshot.mdb.SnapshotMDB  - SnapshotMDB Ctor is called\r",
  "@version" => "1",
      "host" => "bts10d1",
      "path" => "D:\\ElasticSearch\\logstash-1.4.2\\Dashboard_A\\Log_1\\6.log",
      "type" => "dashboard_a",
   "Logdate" => "26-08-2014 11:16:18,021",
  "Severity" => "DEBUG",
     "Class" => "com.fnx.snapshot.mdb.SnapshotMDB",
     "Stack" => " - SnapshotMDB Ctor is called\r"
  }
```

*ElasticSearch result*

```
{
    "_index": "logstash-2014.08.28",
    "_type": "dashboard_a",
    "_id": "-y23oNeLQs2mMbyz6oRyew",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        **"@timestamp": "2014-08-28T14:31:38.753Z",
        **"message": "15:07,565 [DEBUG] com.fnx.snapshot.mdb.SnapshotMDB  - SnapshotMDB Ctor is called\r",
        "@version": "1",
        "host": "bts10d1",
        "path": "D:\\ElasticSearch\\logstash-1.4.2\\Dashboard_A\\Log_1\\6.log",
        "type": "dashboard_a",
        "tags": ["_grokparsefailure"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure all  your logs is in format!

You can see in the logstash  command line trace the logs is

> 26-08-2014 11:16:18,021 [DEBUG] com.fnx.snapshot.mdb.SnapshotMDB  - SnapshotMDB Ctor is called\r

But, in the elastsicsearch the log is

> 15:07,565 [DEBUG] com.fnx.snapshot.mdb.SnapshotMDB  - SnapshotMDB Ctor is called\r",

Two logs have different time and their format are not same! The second one do not have any information about daytime, therefore it will cause the `grok filter` parsing error. You can go to check the origin logs. Or can you provide the origin logs sample for more discussion if all of them are in format!